# g++ power function included in g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++

can power function be used to calulate the power of very large values like pow(200,200).
also can it be used for long long int values ... pow(long long int,long long int).

i am getting this error
/sources/tested.cpp: In function 'int main()':

/sources/tested.cpp:16: error: call of overloaded 'pow(long long int&, long long int&)' is ambiguous

/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:154: note: candidates are: double pow(double, double)

/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux/4.0.1/../../../../include/c++/4.0.1/cmath:360: 
note:                 long double std::pow(long double, int)

/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux/4.0.1/../../../../include/c++/4.0.1/cmath:356: note:                 float std::pow(float, int)

/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux/4.0.1/../../../../include/c++/4.0.1/cmath:352: note:                 double std::pow(double, int)
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux/4.0.1/../../../../include/c++/4.0.1/cmath:348: note:                 long double std::pow(long double, long double)

/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux/4.0.1/../../../../include/c++/4.0.1/cmath:344: note:                 float std::pow(float, float)

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to do arbitrary precision math, you'll need to get a library for it. Likely, your platform doesn't have data types large enough to do so natively. Check out [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the error messages, there is no `pow` function that works on two `long long int` values. The compiler tries to automatically convert the `long long int` values to something else (`double` or `long` etc.). but it can't unambiguously decide which function to take.

You can't use the standard `pow` function to compute very large numbers such as `pow(200, 200)`, because the result doesn't fit in any data type for which the `pow` function is defined - you'll get an overflow or other 'wrong' answer.

Comment: its the spoj error but when i am running the same on my system it works fine

Comment: What 'works fine'? You can compile `pow(200, 200)`, but do you get the correct answer?